# Opening an image file in the output screen

Tags: c, image, winapi, turbo-c

I want to create a photo viewer kind of software using C. But i am stuck at the point thinking that how would i load an image file in the output screen of C in Windows OS?

Answer (score 3):

Forget about Turbo C. It's not going to work for the following reasons:

1. Windows does not support DOS applications well anymore. Starting with Windows Vista, the support is severely reduced and on 64-bit versions of Windows starting with Vista DOS applications can't run at all. The only option is to run DOS apps in a virtual machine of some sort. [DosBox](http://dosbox.org/) can help somewhat, but it's far from being perfect.
2. DOS applications don't support long and non-ASCII names well.
3. DOS applications are limited in how much memory they can allocate and access and nowadays fairly typical JPEG images can be greater than several megabytes. 16-bit applications produced with Turbo C will be typically limited to just a few hundreds of kilobytes.

If you want a Windows app, learn to program using Windows APIs, either directly (via GDI or DirectX) or indirectly through some libraries such as [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

Answer (score 1):

1, Consider up-to-date IDE like Dev-C++, MSVC Express, Eclipse CDT or whatever instead of Turbo C

2, Take a look ak GDI+

3, Follow this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5065/Thumbnails-viewer-and-image-processing-using-GDI-a)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) for displaying images in C. It is primarily meant for game development but allows displaying images easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think openCV library may be instresting for you . Also it has so strong functions which maybe useful for you in the future when you want to improve your project .

For example opening a image is as easy as ;

```
IplImage *img = 0;
img = cvLoadImage( "filename.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
cvNamedWindow( "image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cvShowImage( "image", img );
```

Comment: Which header files do i need to include for these libraries?